# T-SQL replacing day and month when setting datetime variable value on SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

When I'm setting `datetime` variable value the day and month is switched.

For example:

```
declare @date datetime = '2017-12-02 14:56:24.000'
select datepart(month,@date)
```

The result should be 12 but it's 2. The problem exists only on SQL Server 2017. The same code on 2016 returns 12.

Comment: Use a format that is not sensitive to language or other connection settings - as @lad2025 suggests. To understand this better, read [this](http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes)

Comment: why are you using datetime instead of datetime2? you wouldnt have this issue there?

Comment: One of the **many** reasons why one should stop using `DATETIME` and use the `DATETIME2(n)` datatype - introduced in SQL Server **2008**- instead. That datatype does **NOT** show the same behavior - the datetime is always correctly interpreted as you expect it to be

Comment: Using datetime2 change nothing as I tested.

Comment: yes it does. using the rextester from the answer you accepted http://rextester.com/LDX87286

Comment: Using `DATETIME2(3)` instead of `DATETIME` **DOES** just work - tested it on SQL Server 2014, 2016 and 2017. Same behavior everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem exist only on SQL Server 2017. The same code on 2016 returns 12.

It does not depend on SQL Server version, just different [`DATEFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql) settings:

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd; 
declare @date datetime = '2017-12-02 14:56:24.000';
select datepart(month,@date);
-- 12

SET DATEFORMAT ydm;
declare @date2 datetime = '2017-12-02 14:56:24.000';
select datepart(month,@date2);
-- 2
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/HNAIY1735)**

---

To avoid this I suggest to use culture independent **[ISO-8601](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977(v=sql.90).aspx)** date format.

```
declare @date datetime = '2017-12-02T14:56:24.000';
```

**[Rextester Demo2](http://rextester.com/CFA56710)**

or as [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) suggested change datatype to `DATETIME2`:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME2 = '2017-12-02 14:56:24.000';
```

**[Rextester Demo3](http://rextester.com/WORUH39396)**

Comment: Or just use `DATETIME2(n)` instead `DATETIME` - the recommendation since SQL Server **2008** ....